# Programmatically write and submit a smart contract

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-node, smart-contract

Title. Any ways to accomplish this? Preferrably in react/javascript

Edit: downvote me to oblivion!!

Comment: To avoid being downvoted, try to add more detail to your question instead of just writing "Title". If you post a vague question, you'll most likely only get a vague answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [plu-ts](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/smart-contracts/plu-ts) to create a smart contract in Typescript, and then use [Mesh (Web3 SDK)](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/mesh/overview) in your React project to interact with the Smart Contract.